# How to restore percona database from kubernetes?

Tags: restore, percona-server

I got the backup works by setting these on the helm chart values (it works according to the documentation):

```
    google-cloud-storage-s3:
      type: s3
      s3:
        bucket: gcp_bucket
        credentialsSecret: google-cloud-storage-s3-backup
        region: us-west2
        endpointUrl: https://storage.googleapis.com/
```

It's uploaded successfully on the google cloud storage:
[image: backup successful]

Then I tried to restore the backup:

```
gsutil -m cp -r \                                      
  "gs://gcp_bucket/percona-2021-05-06-00:00:11-full.md5" \
  "gs://gcp_backup/percona-2021-05-06-00:00:11-full.sst_info/" \
  "gs://gcp_backup/percona-2021-05-06-00:00:11-full/" \
  .
| [1.1k/1.1k files][  2.7 GiB/  2.7 GiB] 100% Done 942.3 KiB/s ETA 00:00:00     
Operation completed over 1.1k objects/2.7 GiB. 

sudo apt install percona-server-server percona-xtrabackup-80
```

The [documentation](https://www.percona.com/doc/kubernetes-operator-for-pxc/backups.html#copy-backup-to-a-local-machine) said:

```
service mysqld stop
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/*
cat xtrabackup.stream | xbstream -x -C /var/lib/mysql # --> where is this from?
xtrabackup --prepare --target-dir=/var/lib/mysql 
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
service mysqld start
```

The problem is, I could not find any file named `copy-backup.sh` or `xtrabackup.stream` in the backup directories, is there other way to restore the backup, also all files compressed with lz4?
[image: backup content]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `copy-backup.sh` can be found on the [repo](https://github.com/percona/percona-xtradb-cluster-operator/tree/main/deploy/backup)

Then following the commands on the documentation will produce `xtrabackup.stream` file.